# End Tag for head which is not finished?

Tags: php, xhtml

I've been working on a website, and we've been asked to encorporate php, and to use headers/footers. My work is error free except for an "End tage for head which is not finished error" I've moved the end tag for head all over the place and cant figure out why it still throws the error. How can I fix this stupid error when I validate

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../seltzerr/css/webd2201.css" /> 
        <!--
    Author: Ryan Seltzer 
    Filename: header.php    Date: 2015-02-19    Description: This file is the header for all of my web pages, it includes the styling of the page, colors, banner and all of the links to my other web pages
and will be implemented on future assignments as well.-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <a href="http://www.durhamcollege.ca">
        <img src="./images/dclogo.jpg" alt="Durham College Logo"/>
        </a>
        <h1>
            Ryan Seltzer's Website
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="sites">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://opentech.durhamcollege.ca/~pufferd/intn2201/">INTN2201</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://validator.w3.org">XHTML Validator</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/">CSS Validator</a></li>            
            <li><a href="http://php.net/manual/en/index.php">PHP Manual</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.durhamcollege.ca">Durham College</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content-container">
        <div id="navigation">
            <h3>
                Navigation Bar
            </h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../seltzerr/index.php">Home Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab1.php">Lab 1: Basic XHTML pages</a></li>
                <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab2.php">Lab 2: Working with HTML Tables</a></li>
                <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab3.php">Lab 3: Formatting and Layout with Styles</a></li>
                <li><a href="../seltzerr/termtest1.php">Term Test 1: Practical</a></li>
                <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4.php">Lab 4: PHP Chapter Files from textbook</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4phptags.php">Lab 4: PHP Start and End Tags</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4firstscript.php">Lab 4: PHP Code Cohabitation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4errorscript.php">Lab 4: PHP Escaping Your Code</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4errorscript2.php">Lab 4: PHP Escaping Your Code Part 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4comments.php">Lab 4: PHP Commenting Your Code </a></li>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4printvarscript.php">Lab 4: PHP Variable and Value Types</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4constants.php">Lab 4: PHP Using Constants </a></li>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4constants2.php">Lab 4: PHP Using Constants 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4assignscript.php">Lab 4: PHP Assignment Operators</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4comparisonscript.php">Lab 4: PHP Comparison Operators</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../seltzerr/lab4logicalscript.php">Lab 4: PHP Logical Operators</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content"><!--
    Author: Ryan Seltzer 
    Filename: header.php    Date: 2015-02-19    Description: This file is the header for all of my web pages, it includes the styling of the page, colors, banner and all of the links to my other web pages
and will be implemented on future assignments as well.-->
            <h2>Ryan Seltzer's Home         </h2>
            <p>This page was created for the class <a href ="http://opentech.durhamcollege.ca/~pufferd/intn2201">WebD2201</a> 
at <a href="http://www.durhamcollege.ca">Durham College</a> as a home page for
all of the assignments given over the course of this semester. The objective of this
website is to serve as a home page for all of the coming assignments. It will have links
to each assignment done and will follow a similar shape and feel to all assignments.</p>

        <!-- end of main page content -->
        </div>      
        <div id="footer">
        <!-- start of footer -->
                <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">
                    <img    style="width:88px;
                                height:31px;"
                            src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10" 
                            alt="Valid XHTML 1.0 Strict" />
                </a>
                <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
                        <img    style="width:88px;
                                    height:31px;"
                                src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss"
                                alt="Valid CSS!" />
                </a>
                &copy; Ryan Seltzer, 2015
        <!-- end of footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is giving you that error? Where do you see it?

Comment: It says line 11 colum 7 in the w3 validator

Comment: Can you show the source code after the PHP has been parsed?

Comment: *"My work is error free"* + *"cant figure out why it still throws the error"* - You're contradicting yourself. Plus, what is this supposed to do `<?php $title ?>`? It's just a variable sitting in limbo. Your file is `.php`, right?

Comment: what does the php var $title yield when rendered?

Comment: The commenting out code is completely intentional, it calls the var when I run it on the server and is part of my assignments requirements

Comment: *"How can I fix this stupid error when I validate"* - What error is that?

Comment: I don't see a title tag there btw

Comment: @RamRaider When the code runs it calls what is in the var, it only shows how it did before on my notepad with the include statements.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Read the question and the other comments and you'll see it

Comment: I read it countless times and I still don't grasp the question. What you have in your comment saying *"This file is the header for all of my web pages, it includes the styling of the page, colors, banner and all of the links to my other web pages"* - is the part I don't get. What exactly do you mean by that; are you trying to include PHP directives in `<head></head>`?

Comment: i didnt mean the html comments, thats my bad for misleading you. The question was how can I fix the error saying that my head tag shouldnt end yet.

Comment: have you tried with a standard <title</title> tag pair?

Comment: @RamRaider Just changed that and it gets rid of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the page does not have a `<title>` element. This is required.

Best thing to do is put your code into http://validator.w3.org/ and it usually gives you useful messages about what's wrong.

In this case it will show...

> blah blah blah Another possibility is that you used an element which requires a child
>   element that you did not include. Hence the parent element is "not
>   finished", not complete. **For instance, in HTML the `<head>` element must
>   contain a `<title>` child element**, lists require appropriate list items blah blah blah

Comment: I did put it in w3 and it gave that useless error. I'll get rid of the $title  for a standard <title> and see if it fixes.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a part of the error message, it even specifically mentions the title element (I guess this is a common problem)